# I want to know about package managers in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, pip, npm

I have searched on internet but am unable to find complete solution of this question.

What is difference between `pip`, `npm` and `bower` in Ubuntu and is there any other package manager for any other utility softwares?

Comment: I consider "package managers" more something in relation to an OS (like `apt` for Debian, `pacman` and `yast` for other Linux systems).  The 3 you describe are more framework dependent (so have only a meaning when using that frawework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can explain the usage of the 3 you mentioned:

- [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/) is for installing python packages.
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) is the default package manager for the JavaScript runtime environment `Node.js`.
- [bower](https://bower.io/) is front-end package management software (it depends on `Node.js` and `npm`. Also make sure that git is installed as some bower packages require it to be fetched and installed).

And there is also [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/) for installing ruby package.

And for Perl there is [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/).

These installer helpers are specific to the framework you use.

Answer (score 3):

- pip: for Python
- npm: for javascript
- bower: "for the web", aka "HTML, CSS, JavaScript, fonts or even image files"

But there are other package manager as well, like Ubuntu Software Center or `apt-get`, or Synaptic.
Your question, at the state of art, is not entirely understandable, because it is missing what you mean by "package", and a lot of people would assume that you mean .deb files or snap packages, through which you can install programs in Ubuntu.